# Shortcut for moving tabs in Mac Terminal application?

Tags: macos, tabs, terminal, move

I am looking for a shortcut to move the current tab left and right through the tab list. Note that I don't want to **switch** to the left or right tab with the **Cmd+{**, **Cmd+}** shortcuts, but to **move** the tab.

Comment: I'm trying to do this same thing and everyone is answering the same thing you said you're *not* trying to do. :facepalm:

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/852416/how-to-move-the-first-tab-of-terminal-to-the-end-using-applescript

Answer (score 3):

try iterm2, http://iterm2.com/#/section/home

command + left or right arrow to switch tabs

command + shift + left or right to move tabs

Answer (score 3):

According to Terminal -> Preference -> General,

Command + Ordinal can be used to switch tabs, (Ordinal between 1 to 9)

e.g.: Command + 1: switch to the first tab (left-most tab).

Answer (score 3):

you can add a shortcut to have command+left/right arrow go to previous/next tab:

[image: macos preferences keyboard shortcuts]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to move tabs using keyboard on Terminal app.

I would need to drag them by cursor or try iTerm2 instead.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can, and it doesn't appear on any shortcut list i have seen for any browser or application :/ 
however there seems to be a plugin of sorts for Chrome which does this:
 [plugin link that might work.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-reo/moigagbiaanpboaflikhdhgdfiifdodd?hl=en)